# How to verify if input is not a letter or string?

Tags: python-3.x, input, menu

I'm writing a basic program in IDLE with a menu choice with options from 1 to 4.
If a user input anything else then a number, it gives a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
How can I check if the input is not a letter, and if it is, print a error message of my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def isNumber (value):
    try:
        floatval = float(value)
        if floatval in (1,2,3,4):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False

number_choice = input('Please choose a number: 1, 2, 3 or 4.\n')

while isNumber(number_choice) == False:
    number_choice = input('Please choose a number: 1, 2, 3 or 4.\n')
else:
    print('You have chosen ' + number_choice + '.\n')
```

This will check if the number is 1,2,3 or 4 and if not will ask the user to input the number again until it meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly unclear on whether you wish to test whether something is an integer or whether it is a letter, but I am responding to the former possibility.

```
    user_response = input("Enter an integer: ")

    try:
        int(user_response)
        is_int = True
    except ValueError:
        is_int = False

    if is_int:
        print("This is an integer! Yay!")
    else:
        print("Error. The value you entered is not an integer.")
```

I am fairly new to python, so there might very well be a better way of doing this, but that is how I have tested whether or not input values are integers in the past.

Comment: Using your method, I can get it to print if it is in int value. Anything else give me a traceback error.

Comment: What do you want to do with the information about whether or not it is an integer? It might be helpful if you posted the code you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha()` - it is a string method which checks that whether a string entered is alphabet or words(only alphabets, no spaces or numeric) or not

```
        while True:
            user_response = input("Enter an integer : ")
            if user_response.isalpha():
                print("Error! The value entered is not an integer")
                continue
            else:
                print("This is an integer! Yay!")
                break
```

This program is having infinite loop i.e. until you enter an integer this program will not stop. I have used break and continue keyword for this.